# Updating Record with ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on calling up a pre-populated form based on user input.  I want to allow editing of the record in the resulting form, and then save the updates to the DB Record.  Below is creating new records, not updating existing and I'm stuck on next steps.

```
   def mod_customer(request):
        params = json.loads(request.body)
        selection = params['cst_id']
        obj = AppCustomerCst.objects.get(id_cst=selection)
        instance = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, id_cst=selection)
        form = CustomerMaintForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if '_edit' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('customers')
    
        elif form.is_valid() and '_delete' in request.POST:
            # just for testing purposes. once mod is working, will update with delete
            # AppCustomerCst.objects.filter(id_cst=selection).delete()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'mod_customer.html', context=context)
    
    
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'mod_customer.html', context=context)
```

Comment: if your request.body is a JSON type, request.POST could be empty because a request can not parse a JSON string to QueryDict.

Comment: @Blackdoor thank you for pointing that out, I think that is indeed part of the problem.  So now I get past that with a try and except on the JSon, and I can see the Form Post with new data, but it doesn't actually update the record.  This got me on to the next steps though, thank you!

Comment: Because request.POST always is empty, the last `else ` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is after @BlackDoor step.

Your code might not reach form.save(). That is why the records are not being updated.

To know for sure do something like print(form.is_valid()) if this is **False** then do **form.errors** to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I have a print statement after the 'if form.is_valid()' and it's hitting that print statement; still not saving.

Comment: Added the `print(form.is_valid())` like you suggested, it's showing True.

Comment: can you add  your model and your form as well? Maybe that will help more to find the problem